# WP logout when upload on front

Tags: wordpress, logout, capability, wp-editor

My theme have a submit post page and I configure user capabilities for everyone to  upload.

But no one can able to upload. And when i clicked "add media" button and select any file for upload, my current account is logging out automatically.

Where at, after user try upload, Visitors to the position falls. What do you think? Why logout?

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to say. I'm unable to understand it properly..

Answer (score 2):

**Why WordPress Keeps Logging Out?**

WordPress sets a cookie in your browser to authenticate a login session. This cookie is set for the WordPress URL stored in your settings section.

If you are accessing from a URL that does not match the one in your WordPress settings, then WordPress will not be able to authenticate your session.

**Fixing The Login Issue**

A simple fix for this login issue is to make sure that you have the same URL in your Site Address and WordPress Address fields in your WordPress settings.

This means that you need to choose either www or a non-www URL in the both fields.

> Login to your WordPress dashboard and go to Settings » General.

If you can’t access the admin area, then you can update these fields by editing the `wp-config.php` file.

Connect to your website using an FTP client, and locate the `wp-config.php` file in your site’s root directory. You need to download this file to your Desktop and open it in a text editor like Notepad. Add this code just above the line That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

If you prefer to use www in URL, then use this code instead

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

[image: correct settings]

[complete reference](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-keeps-logging-out-problem/)

Comment: my website don't have problem with normally. but i added new post submit page. my problem is in this page while uploading any file.

Comment: what you are trying to upload on the new post. featured image?

Comment: no, any media object to post content. i use wp_editor with add media button. try upload with this button, user auto-logout suddenly. because of upload not success.

Comment: See it may be session problem I will post the answer below kind suggestion your question not clear try to frame a clear question and check it once with anyone they can understand or not. Because it may cause some waste of time while we are referring correct solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you

To find out what the default (file-based-sessions) session timeout value on the server is you can view it through a ini_get command:

```
// Get the current Session Timeout Value
$currentTimeoutInSecs = ini_get(’session.gc_maxlifetime’);
```

Change the Session Timeout Value

```
// Change the session timeout value to 30 minutes  // 8*60*60 = 8 hours
ini_set(’session.gc_maxlifetime’, 30*60);
//————————————————————————————–

// php.ini setting required for session timeout.

 ini_set(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’,30);
 ini_set(‘session.gc_probability’,1);
 ini_set(‘session.gc_divisor’,1);
 //————————————————————————————–
 //if you want to change the  session.cookie_lifetime.
 //This required in some common file because to get the session values in  whole application we need to write session_start();  to each file then only will   get $_SESSION global variable values.

$sessionCookieExpireTime=8*60*60;
session_set_cookie_params($sessionCookieExpireTime);
session_start();
```

// Reset the expiration time upon page load //session_name() is default name of session PHPSESSID

```
 if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
 setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + $sessionCookieExpireTime, “/”);
 //————————————————————————————–
 //To get the session cookie set param values.

 $CookieInfo = session_get_cookie_params();

 echo “<pre>”;
 echo “Session information session_get_cookie_params function :: <br />”;
 print_r($CookieInfo);
 echo “</pre>”;
 //————————————————————————————–
```

Some Description of session related setting for php.ini file.

session.gc_maxlifetime integer
session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as ‘garbage’ and cleaned up. Garbage collection occurs during session start.
session.cookie_lifetime integer

session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser.

The value 0 means “until the browser is closed.” Defaults to 0. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

Since the cookie is returned by the browser, it is not prolonged to suffice the lifetime. It must be sent manually by setcookie().

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was caused with HTTPS activation and param *$secure_cookie* of **wp_signon** function setted as **false instead of true/empty**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/

```
$creds = [
  'user_login'    => $user_login,
  'user_password' => $password,
  'remember'      => 'true',
];
$signon = wp_signon($creds, true); // <<< USE true OR REMOVE PARAM
```