# wordpress Async-upload.php diverts me to login page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, asynchronous, file-upload, wordpress-login

I am using wp media upload on frond end  to upload image, but when i upload image from front end and upload gives me error can not uploaded i see that when ajax make call to `'async-upload.php'` it logout me and divert to wp dashboard login page

Comment: I had the same issue on HTTPS activation, and this was the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59492086/3740246

Answer (score 5):

If you have already tried disabling all plugins, modifying role capabilities, and adding the suggested lines to your .htaccess file, the following actions worked for me. Go to /wp-admin/admin.php. Locate the line that says:

```
    auth_redirect();
```

And replace it with:

```
    if (!defined("DOING_AJAX"))
        auth_redirect();
```

This solution worked for me, but note that these changes will most likely be overwritten when you update your version of Wordpress.

EDIT:
After some Wordpress updates, I have had to change the way I go about solving this, instead of including the /wp-admin/admin.php, I had to copy the file into async-uploads.

I also had to go into ajax-actions.php and include the following lines at the top of the file:

```
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it still have problem. can you give me another way to fix?