# wordpress Frontend media upload logout user

Tags: wordpress

I have face one issue when user wordpress media up-loader fronted side. Also i assign upload file permeation for that user role. The same thing working my local server to. But when i move on live server when i click on upload button media upload popup open. When i select file for upload its give me error "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

When i refresh page user logout so this happen. so i think when i try to upload image user logout auto.

On live server : 
Wordpress version 4.7.3 / php version 7

Local server :
wordpress version 4.7.3 / Php Version 5.6.24

Comment: I am facing the same problem for this, Could you please tell have you found any solution?

Comment: How about explaining and sharing the solution that you found, please?

Comment: I had the same issue on HTTPS activation, and this was the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59492086/3740246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the permission of the upload folder first, if that is fine, please check all your plugins if anyone of them causing this issue. You can disable then one by one and then check.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I check that all thing but not success.

Comment: Can you please provide more details i.e screenshot/used plugin list Or the url of the site so that we can test that.

Comment: Thanks for your replay . I found solution and now its working fine.

Comment: How about explaining and sharing that solution please?